# SQL - check if the dates are in correct sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like this:

```
id    start      end
1     1-1-2015   29-1-2015
2     30-1-2015  28-2-2015
3     1-3-2015   30-3-2015
....
```

Now I need `sql` query which will check if any date is missed between the `end date` of row and `start dat`e of next row.

E.g. if the `end date` is `29-1-2015` then `start date` of next row should always be the next date of that i.e. `30-1-2015`.
If any date is missed then it should return an error.

Comment: Side note: I might recommend that you start recording periods using an *exclusive* end point. That way, the start value of one period should be the end value of another period - and that's a simple comparison to perform. (Also, if you want to, with some special handling for the first period, you can actually implement a foreign key and ensure "wrong" data doesn't get in there in the first place)

Comment: Can there be gaps in the ids?  Do you care about the ordering of the values?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get the next record (assuming you are defining next by using the order of ID), then just filter out those where the start of the next record does not match the end of the current record:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    YourTable AS T1
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 T2.[Start]
            FROM    YourTable AS T2
            WHERE   T2.ID > T1.ID
            ORDER BY T2.ID
        ) AS NextStart
WHERE   NextStart.[Start] != DATEADD(DAY, 1, T1.[End]);
```

If your id column has no gaps, you could just use a join:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    YourTable AS T1
        INNER JOIN YourTable AS NextStart
            ON T2.ID = T.ID + 1
WHERE   NextStart.[Start] != DATEADD(DAY, 1, T.[End]);
```

---

If the start of one period should always be the day after the end of the previous, why not just store a single value for this. e.g. All you need to store is:

```
id    start     
1     2015-01-01  
2     2015-01-30 
3     2015-03-01
```

Now, you can define your end date, by looking for the next start date:

```
SELECT  t.id,
        t.start,
        [end] = DATEADD(DAY, -1, e.start)
FROM    dbo.YourTable AS t
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 start
            FROM    dbo.YourTable AS T2
            WHERE   t2.ID > t.ID
            ORDER BY ID
        ) AS e;
```

You can then make this a view if you need both the start and the end regularly, and it ensures that you do not have any missing periods.

Answer (score 1):

Try with simple join:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( id INT, s DATE, e DATE )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, '20150101', '20150129' ),
        ( 2, '20150130', '20150228' ),
        ( 3, '20150301', '20150330' ),
        ( 4, '20150501', '20150630' );

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id ) AS id ,
                        s ,
                        e
               FROM     @t
             )
    SELECT  c2.id ,
            c1.id
    FROM    cte c1
            JOIN cte c2 ON c2.id + 1 = c1.id
    WHERE   DATEADD(d, 1, c2.e) <> c1.s
```

Output:

```
id  id
3   4
```

First you are numbering rows with continuous numbers. Then you are joining row on next row and check if adding 1 day to prev row value gives you the next row value.

Simply remove `CTE` if you have continuous `id`s already.